# Unit Testing using gradle from terminal for CI

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I've been trying to use unit tests with Android Studio and Gradle, but right now I'm concentrated in making all the test run using ./gradlew test. The problem is I'm getting the following errors from a library in the project:

```
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    private MockContext context;
            ^
  symbol:   class MockContext
  location: class ITEventsAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITAssociationAPI.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcAssociationsByEventID = new RestClient("");
        ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITAssociationAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITAssociationAPI.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcAssociationsByEventID = new RestClient("");
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITAssociationAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcLeadsByEventID = new RestClient(base_url + "/rest/event/" + EVENT_ID);
        ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITEventsAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcLeadsByEventID = new RestClient(base_url + "/rest/event/" + EVENT_ID);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITEventsAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcTagsCode = new RestClient(base_url + "/rest/event/tags");
        ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITEventsAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcTagsCode = new RestClient(base_url + "/rest/event/tags");
                                    ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITEventsAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcLeadEventsByTag = new RestClient(base_url + "/rest/eventtag/" + TAG + "/events");
        ^
  symbol:   class RestClient
  location: class ITEventsAPI
/Users/Radsen/Projects/Mobile/AllianceTech/androidstudio/ATDroidUtils/app/src/test/java/com/alliancetech/ileadsalpha/ITEventsAPI.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        RestClient rcLeadEventsByTag = new RestClient(base_url + "/rest/eventtag/" + TAG + "/events");
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alliancetech.ileadsalpha"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

configurations{
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    compile project(':atdroidutilslib')

    //unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //unitTestCompile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    unitTestCompile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
    unitTestCompile project(':atdroidutilslib')
}

task iLeadsIntegrationTests(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}
check.dependsOn iLeadsIntegrationTests
```

Answer (score 0):

After working for almost 2 days on this, I decided to retry some of the posts I saw and this one helped me solving my issue. Here is the link:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support.

Comment: To solve the problem I had here, I followed the link I posted from another answer. But I'm having other using it from Jenkins. Can you tell me if you are capable of running the test from your workstation using the console?